# Launch application with arguments with NSWorkspace not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstask, nsworkspace

I would like to open FileZilla (ftp application) with an argument.

It is working with **NSTask** (aka. Process):

```
let process:Process = Process()
process.launchPath = appURL.path
process.arguments = ["ftp://1.2.3.4"]
process.launch()
```

It is not working with **NSWorkspace**:

```
try! NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication(
   at: appURL,
   options: .default,
   configuration: [NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments:["ftp://1.2.3.4"]]
)
```

With *not working* I mean, that FileZilla launches, but the argument is not passed over.

The API seems simple, but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here.

The reason why I want to use NSWorkspace is, that NSTask the application will not launch in foreground.

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigrationArguments isn't available to sandboxed apps https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspacelaunchconfigurationarguments

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But why NSTask is not blocked, remains a mystery . :/ My workaround for now is to use NSTask to open the application with an argument and then use NWorkspace to bring the application the front. Does anyone know a better solution for a sandboxed app?

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617643/swift-on-macos-open-chrome-with-a-url-as-parameter

Answer (score 0):

I am using a `launchAgent` to run a script that runs my app, I found that if we need to pass a configuration, we need to wait a little bit after executing the open function:

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.open(appURL, configuration: configuration)
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
```

Comment: Hi Hadi, can you confirm that this works with a sandboxed app for the Mac App Store?

Comment: I can't confirm that, my app isn't sandboxed.